# Getting data from array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im trying to use API. I get data coded in JSON in array.

Now I need to encode the array to get the value I need, but don't know exactly how to do it. I want to get pln value.

This is what I get:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { 
    ["status"]=> string(2) "ok" 
    ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (4) {   
        ["pln"]=> string(6) "0.0000" 
        ["usd"]=> string(6) "0.0000" 
        ["btc"]=> string(10) "0.00000000" 
        ["eur"]=> string(6) "0.0000" 
    } 
}
```

Orginal API code:

```
function getBalance($url){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$url = $main_api_url.'balance/'.$api_user_id.'/'.$api_key.'/'.$api_secret.'/';

var_dump(
json_decode(
    getBalance($url)
)
);
```

This is my code:

```
function getBalance($url){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$url = $main_api_url.'balance/'.$api_user_id.'/'.$api_key.'/'.$api_secret.'/';

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

print "$data[pln]";
```

How I can get exactly pln value? Im not interested in whole array.

Comment: Can you put `<pre>` before var_dump $data ? Not sure but i think u can access 'pln' like this `$data->data->pln`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the modified version, since it returns an array, you can point it directly:

```
echo $data['data']['pln'];
```

So finally:

```
function getBalance($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$url = $main_api_url.'balance/'.$api_user_id.'/'.$api_key.'/'.$api_secret.'/';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo $data['data']['pln'];
       //   ^ its inside data
```